# Defining a xml for representing adjacency list of graphs?

Tags: python, xml, graph, xml-parsing, adjacency-list

I am working on a python graph library and I am using adjacency list. I am thinking about using xml to represent the adjacency list so it will be easier for me to store to or read from graphs.
For a graph like this:

```
  A
  |\
  | \
  |  \
  B---C
```

the adjacency will look like

A:[B,C]

B:[A,C]

C:[A,B]

The question comes here, how will you convert it into xml? I have a (very) limited xml knowledge so mine looks like:

```
<graph>
     <node>
     A
     <realtedto>[B,C]</relatedto>
     </node>
     ...
</graph>
```

Does this look right to you? And also, how will you deal with the issue that the graph may be not simple or directional?

Answer (score 2):

Welp, you could store your links like so:

```
<graph>
 <node id="A" />
 <node id="B" />
 <node id="C" />
 <links>
  <link first="A" second="B" />
  <link first="A" second="C" />
 </links>
</graph>
```

But, then you have strange situations like "is A, B the same as B, A"? if you're doing lookups. I would probably not ever go with the above way. On the other hand, if you do it that way you aren't storing duplicate information. (potentially, if you validate to prevent reversals). If it's a digraph then that side effect might be a feature, since A,B **IS** different than B,A in that case.

Keep in mind that xml implicitly stores things in a hierarchy, and a graph is not necessarily a hierarchy without a transformation, so it's impossible to represent "directly" without some sort of contortion. I'd probably do something like this:

```
<graph>
<node id="A">
  <neighbors>
   <neighbor id="B" />
   <neighbor id="C" />
  </neighbors>
</node>
<node id="B">
  <neighbors>
   <neighbor id="A" />
  </neighbors>
</node>
<node id="C">
  <neighbors>
   <neighbor id="A" />
  </neighbors>
</node>
</graph>
```

Unfortunately you have duplicated information, but you get around the ordering issues, and if you deserialize it you always have a reference to a node's neighbors for traversal. If you wanted it to be a digraph you could separate  `<neighbors>` into `<inlets>` and `<outlets>`. OR just `<neighbor>` tag on the outlet side, if you don't care about being able to traverse backwards.

You could combine the two approaches if you wanted to be able to iterate through your links.

It all comes down to the features you want your data to have.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that XML is a poor fit for modeling arbitrary graphs: it is a tree-modeling language.